# Mageto - Filter Category Navigation in tree like state

Tags: php, magento

I created a code to filter the product collection by categories. Making its own left side block using the following code.

I have it to work perfect for filtering, I am just having a hard time rendering the display.

The Level 2 categories work fine and only show

1. Top Level Category 1
2. Top Level Category 2

Once selected it then shows sub categories and their sub categories..

- Sub Category of 1
- Sub sub category of ^^^
- Sub sub category of ^^^
- Sub sub category of ^^^
- Sub sub sub category of ^^^
- Sub Category of 1
- Sub sub category of ^^^
- Sub sub category of ^^^
- Sub sub category of ^^^
- Sub sub sub category of ^^^

I need it to break down like the first level did. What would be the best method?

```
            <?php
            $root_category_id = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
            $filterCategoryId = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('cat');

            $products = Mage::getSingleton('catalogsearch/advanced')->getProductCollection();
            $catIds = array();
            if (isset($products)) foreach ($products as $product) {
                if ($product->isSaleable()) {
                    $ids = $product->getCategoryIds();
                    foreach ($ids as $id) $catIds[$id] = 1;
                }
            }
            if (!isset($catIds)) return false;

            $categories = array();
            // Filters rest of categories 
            if ($filterCategoryId) {
                $filterCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($filterCategoryId);
                $filterChildren = $filterCategory->getAllChildren(true);

                foreach ($catIds as $id => $x) {
                    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($id);
                    if (in_array($root_category_id, $category->getParentIds()) && in_array($id, $filterChildren) && $id != $filterCategoryId) {
                        $categories[$id] = $category->getName();
                    } else {
                        unset($catIds[$id]);
                    }
                }

            } else {
             // Filters the first level categoires
                foreach ($catIds as $id => $x) {
                    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($id);
                    if (in_array($root_category_id, $category->getParentIds()) && $category->getLevel() == 2) {
                        $categories[$id] = $category->getName();
                    } else {
                        unset($catIds[$id]);
                    }
                }
            }

    if(isset($categories) && sizeof($categories) > 0):
        $url = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRequesturi();
        $url = Mage::helper("core/url")->removeRequestParam($url, 'cat');
        ?>
        <div class="page-subtitle" style="margin:6px auto 14px 6px;"><h2>Shop By Category</h2></div>
        <ul class="brandsnav">
            <?php foreach($categories as $id=>$name): ?>
                <li class="cf">
                <span class="subnav_trigger"></span>
                    <a href="<?php 
    echo Mage::helper("core/url")->addRequestParam($url, array("cat"=>$id)); ?>"><?php echo $name;?></a>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to add conditions to the foreach statements. Got it working.